# Express parameter from route in mongodb match clause

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express

I have a piece of code that doesn't work. I'm trying to get value out of my route. you can see I log my value of req.param.val2, which in my case is 1.

```
apiRoutes.get('/val1/:val2/:val3', function(req, res) {

console.log(req.params.val3);
console.log(req.params.val2);

val1.aggregate([
    {
        $match:
            {
                val2:req.params.val2
            }
    },
    {
        $sample:{size:1}
    }
],
    function(err, val1) {
        res.json(val);
    })
});
```

When I replace req.params.val2 with the value 1, like here:

```
$match:
{
  val2:1
}
```

The code works. I think I'm making a stupid little mistake but I can't pinpoint what exactly.

Who can ? :)

Comment: When you pass in the value of 1 to the $match query, what is your result? And are you getting errors using the parameter or just not getting what you expected?

Comment: Second question: Is `val1` a reference to a collection? Note the issue with names - Later, you name the second parameter of your callback `val1`, then send back as json `val`.

Comment: When I Pass 1, I get an random mongo document that has val2 set to 1. When I pass req.params.val2 (which in this case is 1, I get an empty array)

Answer (score 0):

I found out what the problem was, and it's pretty depressing.

In mongodb, my document was set like this

```
{
  "_id" : ObjectId("59199fc3d79317d2bc587659"),
  "text" : "some text",
  "level" : 1,
  "val3" : true,
  "val2" : false,
  "val4" : false,
  "val5" : false
}
```

Somehow, the req.params.val2 was of value 1, but type String instead of Number / int.

Resolvable either by converting the value to int or setting al values in database as a String.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to convert the string in integer, like this:

```
$match:
{
  val2 : parseInt(req.params.val2)
}
```